# How to prevent beforeunload from firing when save is selected

Tags: javascript, html, function

I currently have a function that sets "isDirty = true" when a change is made on the page. *Works as expected*
I have a function that only fires when navigating away from the current page after not choosing the save button.

```
function pageChange() {
            if (isDirty == true) {
                window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
                    // Cancel the event
                    e.preventDefault(); 
                    e.returnValue = '';
                    isDirty = false;
                });
            } else {
                return
            }
        }
```

The above works, however, when I click cancel on the alert to stay on the page and then go save the page, the dialog box shows up again.

Answer (score 0):

You could specify the `once` option in the `addEventListener` call:

```
function pageChange() {
    if (isDirty == true) {
        window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
            ...
        }, { once: true });
    }
}
```

[EventTarget.addEventListener() - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)